# Unable to work with Google chrome driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to work with google chrome. I am using the following code to instantiate google chrome driver object. But, when I click "System." and doing ctrl+space for suggestions, its showing "No Default Proposals".

and when writing the full code, it's showing error. See picture.[image: No suggestions for System class][image: Error in adding chrome driver]

Comment: Please know basics of any coding language then start learn automation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with the chrome driver. The problem is you're trying to use it under the `class` level  and not inside a `method`

Place the code inside any method and you will not get any errors.

Comment: Very true...I have seen same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the annotations/method here

something like this

```
 public class Chromedriver{
      WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
   public void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path to chrome driver");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/");
 }
```

Or call the above in main method or a seperate method. Please make sure all the imports are done.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Chrome driver class as well for using selenium with Chrome.

Please try this code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Tester {
private static WebDriver driver = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chrome driver");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.example.com");
driver.quit();
}
}
```